# Display User data using JSON and PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a jSON file and I want to display its data but it show me result in some strange format i don't know where I'm wrong. Here is my PHP code,

```
$json = file_get_contents('data.json'); 
$data = json_decode($json,true);
$users = $data['user'];
foreach($users as $user)
{
echo $user['user'];
}
```

Data in my jSON file below,

```
{
"user":
    {
    "id":"#79F9FFB1EE0CB1CC",
    "user":"test@mail.com",
    "password":"123456",
    "email":"test@mail.com",
    "name":"John Doe",
    "creationDate":1387111401
    },
"status":
    {
    "version":"0.9.9.1",
    "command":"getuser",
    "opf":"json",
    "error":false,
    "code":0
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the outut you're getting? What is the expected output. You can use `var_dump()` or `print_r()` to explore your `$users` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your foreach loop that is wrong.

You only have on user so replace your loop by :

```
$users = $data['user'];
echo $users['user'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$json = '{
"user":
    {
    "id":"#79F9FFB1EE0CB1CC",
    "user":"test@mail.com",
    "password":"123456",
    "email":"test@mail.com",
    "name":"John Doe",
    "creationDate":1387111401
    },
"status":
    {
    "version":"0.9.9.1",
    "command":"getuser",
    "opf":"json",
    "error":false,
    "code":0
    }
}';

$data = json_decode($json,true);
$users = $data['user'];
foreach($users as $key=>$user)
{

 echo $user.'<br>';
}
```